# Unable to connect to AWS centos instance from Oracle Linux Virtualbox

Tags: centos, ssh, aws, oracle-linux

When I am trying to connect to AWS CentOS instance from Linux Oracle I am getting below error:

```
ssh -i "/LinuxTest.pem" centos@ec2-3-7-55-40.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Load key "/LinuxTest.pem": invalid format
```

While I am able to connect with same key from Windows(which is the host machine) from Putty after converting the .pem to .ppk.

Comment: Windows uses two characters to indicate the end of a line: Carriage Return and Line Feed. UNIX uses only Line Feed. I suppose this causes the *invalid format* error. You can convert the file with a tool like `dos2unix`.

Comment: I have used dos2unix on my Linux Virtualbox but still the result is same

Comment: How did you create this private key? Is it an option to post it here? Note that you already published the instance's name.

Comment: I have downloaded it directly from AWS EC2 and using the same I have converted it into .ppk to connect from windows machine(Windows connection is working perfectly fine)

Comment: If you can't share it here (which would be understandable), create a key of the same type with ssh-keygen and compare how they differ.

Comment: How to create a new key using ssh-keygen ? I have downloaded the key from AWS website.

Comment: @Atif `man ssh-keygen`

Comment: Type `ssh-keygen` and follow the prompts. As a first approach, accept defaults.

Comment: Yes, I am able to generate it and below is the message: Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:

Comment: @berndbausch Key generate using ssh-keygen is not the same I have received from AWS i.e. .pem or the one I have generated i.e. .ppk. But why I am able to connect from windows machine and not from linux guest machine

Comment: Without seeing the non-functional key, there is nothing I can add.